# Formula to calculate directly $ 1 + 2 \cdot 3 + 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 + 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 + \dots + n \cdot (n+1) \cdot \dots \ (2n-1)$

Tags: summation, recursion

Is it some formula to calculate $$ 1 + 2 \cdot 3 + 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 + 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 + \dots + n \cdot (n+1) \cdot \dots \ (2n-1)$$

for a given $n$ without iteration?

comes from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480831/recursion-sum-of-series-of-n-terms/34481682#34481682

Comment: It is very unlikely such formula exists.

Comment: @Wojowu fast answer: you can be more precise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$1+2\cdot3+3\cdot4\cdot5+4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7+\dots=\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{3!}{1!}+\frac{5!}{2!}+\frac{7!}{3!}+\dots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n+1)!}{n!}$$

Now, you can show by the limit test, that this series diverges!

---

For a given $m$:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{(2n+1)!}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{2^{2n+1}\Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi}}=\frac{\frac{2^{3+2m}\text{E}_{\frac{5}{2}+m}\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{2}+m\right)}{\sqrt{\pi}}-\text{E}_{\frac{3}{2}}\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)}{4\sqrt[4]{e}}$$

With $\text{E}_n(x)$ is the exponentital integral, and $\Gamma(x)$ is the gamma function.

Comment: sorry, but the question was not about divergence (rather evident), but about is it (and how) calculate it. I precised the question.

Comment: Or bound by $1+1+1+\cdots \leq 1+ 2\cdot 3 + \dots$

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP is asking about a finite sum, not about a series.

Comment: @AlexM: It was yourself who changed the question to be about a finite sum instead of the series that that OP asked about. Don't to that!

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on how you've found the formula for this finite sum?

Comment: Bravo ! I put the point, and I close as soon as someone makes the calculus (or gives me the function in java: I asked it on stackoverflow).

Comment: The second is ok. for the third, I did not find a library for En(x), except for n integer. So I code an integral at hand. It is just some little difference (about 1), surely because of the precision. I close the question